# Como cambiar la ruta inicial

Tags: javascript, python, djangorestframework, django-urls, react-redux

Debo cambiar esta ruta para poder ver los documentos que tengo previamente cargados y no se como sustituir la ruta inicial ya que esta destinada de esta manera al dar click en ver el documento me despliega una nueva ventana con esta ruta

http://backend/media/DocumentVentas/EDC32_OFE_Edison_Jao_dpgeNoo.pdf

y si reemplazo la palabra backend por localhost:8000 en este caso se puede visualizar el documento

http://localhost:8000/media/DocumentVentas/EDC32_OFE_Edison_Jao_dpgeNoo.pdf

asi esta definido el servidor nginx

```
    upstream frontend {
        server ssilva-frontend:3000;
    }
    
    upstream backend {
        server ssilva-backend:8000;
    }
    
    
    server {
        listen 80;
    
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://frontend;
        }
    
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass          http://backend;
        }
    }
```

estas son las Media Files en el settings de python

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

asi mismo encontre una funcion que me retorna un url absoluto para el retorno de los links de los archivos

```
    def get_full_path_x(request):
        full_path = ('http', ('', 's')[request.is_secure()], '://',
                     request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
    
        return ''.join(full_path)
```

y una funcion que como ejemplo en este caso obtiene un documento

```
    def get_fotocopia_carnet_url(self, obj):
            if obj.DocumentFotocopiaCarnet and hasattr(
                    obj.DocumentFotocopiaCarnet, 'url'):
                url = self.context.get('url')
                absolute_url = get_full_path_x(url)
                return "%s%s" % (absolute_url, obj.DocumentFotocopiaCarnet.url)
            else:
                return ""
```

en cuanto al front tenemos el API_ROOT

```
    NODE_ENV=development
    API_ROOT=http://localhost:8000/api
```

el cual segun mi apreciacion es para vincularlo con el django rest  un ejemplo de ello es en este caso el vinculo con las inmobiliarias de este modo

```
    export function* fetchRealEstate() {
      return yield all([
        call(request, `${API_ROOT}/inmobiliarias/`),
        call(request, `${API_ROOT}/constructoras/`),
        call(request, `${API_ROOT}/inmobiliarias-users-types/`),
      ]);
    }
```

Comment: Eso es que ese PDF se ha colocado en `/media/DocumentVentas/EDC32_OFE_Edison_Jao_dpgeNoo.pdf` y si lo quieres ver usando `http://backend/media/DocumentVentas/EDC32_OFE_Edison_Jao_dpgeNoo.pdf` debes colocarlo en `/api/media/DocumentVentas/EDC32_OFE_Edison_Jao_dpgeNoo.pdf`

Comment: O bien puedes probar de abrirlo con `http://frontend/media/DocumentVentas/EDC32_OFE_Edison_Jao_dpgeNoo.pdf`

Comment: masterguru el tema es poder identificar en donde produce ese termino backend para ser reemplazado adjuntare mas terminos que he encontrado con respecto al proyecto